# quantmod::getFX function returns "character in a standard unambiguous format"

Tags: r, quantmod

I have been using `quantmod::getFX` on an almost daily basis recently, and for some reason today it makes my shiny app crashes.

I updated R, all my packages, tried the function on two different computers, but still get the same error.

To replicate the problem:

```
library(quantmod)
getFX("EUR/USD")
```

The error is:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Let me know if you need further information.

Comment: I thought this was due to user error, but running the examples gives the same error. Have you contacted the package maintainer?

Comment: I haven't contacted him, but I will let him know about this post and Patrick's answer below. The changes between timestamps/datetimes seem to be the root of the issue.

Comment: I am aware of this. It has already [been reported](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/144).

Comment: A [fix](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/144#issuecomment-292726265) has been published and it's solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this! I ran into the same error -- quantmod::getFX is a personal favorite for pulling historical FX data in R, so I'm glad there was a fix