# CharToDate(x) Error in R

Tags: r

I have a function named currency. It takes a parameter A which is a currency like "EUR/USD" . Then I do this: n<-getSymbols(A,src = "oanda",from = "2016-01-01",to = Sys.Date(),auto.assign = FALSE)
The paradox is that the program was running fine 2 days ago.
The error message is: Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format.

[This is the traceback()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNRLB.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your code, marked as code  (click the {} when editing). For dates, take a  look at package `lubridate` which has robust functions for date parsing, such as , `ymd`. It is best to follow the posting guidelines in [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this a duplicate

[quantmod::getFX function returns "character in a standard unambiguous format"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289123/quantmodgetfx-function-returns-character-in-a-standard-unambiguous-format)

In any case, I followed the code of the getSymbols.oanda and it seems that oanda changed their API so instead of downloading a .csv you get a .xml file.

Speaking for me, I will go for a different source for the data until this is resolved by the quantmod guys.

Comment: actually the fix is already out, try this command: devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod@144_getFX")